# Guice Resteasy JaxRS Integration

Tags: jax-rs, jetty, guice, resteasy

I am migrating a Jetty - Resteasy to Guice

I have a web.xml to configure Resteasy

it points to a subclass of `javax.ws.rs.Application` class to load resources

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.MyWebApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cacheControl</param-name>
            <param-value>no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and in `MyWebApplication` I use reflection to load all the classes in a specific paclage

```
        try {
            final Set<Class<?>> apiEndpoints = getApiEndpoints();

            for (Class<?> endpoint :apiEndpoints) {               
                singletons.add(endpoint.newInstance());
            }
            // Initialisation for resteasy ProxyFactory
            RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
        } catch( Throwable e ) {
            ...
        }

...

public static Set<Class<?>> geApiEndpoints(){
        final ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().includePackage("com.test.web"))
                .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.test.web"))
                .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(), new TypeAnnotationsScanner());
        final Reflections reflectionUtil = builder.build();
        return reflectionUtil.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class);
    }
```

To start supporting Guice, I changed the listener and added ContextParam

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

        <!-- Guice    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.guice.modules</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.MyAppModule,org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.ext.JaxrsModule</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

MyAppModule has a few bindings for my services

```
        bind(AService.class).to(AServiceImpl.class);
        bind(BPersistenceService.class).to(BPersistenceServiceImpl.class);
        requestStaticInjection(InjectorUtil.class);
```

What I am not doing and expecting the listener to handle is binding the Resources.

Since the `GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener` is the extension of `ResteasyBootstrap`, I was thinking that it would take care of Injecting the Guice Services in the Rest endpoints after they are instantiated and loaded to resteasy. but it is not.

I get a null pointer on aService in my resource class

```
@Path("/foo")
public class Foo{

    private AService aService;

    @Inject
    public setAServuce(final AService aService){
        aService = aService;
    }

    @GET
    @Path(/{id})
    public getA(@PathParam("id") String id){
        return this.aService.get(id);
    }

}
```

It will work if I again iterate over all the rest endpoints and a do a bind on them in AppModule

```
try {
            final Set<Class<?>> apiEndpoints = getApiEndpoints();

            for (Class<?> endpoint :apiEndpoints) {               
                bind(endpoint);
            }
            // Initialisation for resteasy ProxyFactory

            ...
        }
```

But I do not want to load classes twice.

What changes should I make it to get the Guice injecting the instances into the Rest Resources?

on a side note, I want to avoid binding each resource class in the module individually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured one workaround could be that that I can get the singletons from the MyWebApplication class and bind them all in the MyAppModule

`MyWebApplocation.get().getSingletons().forEach(api -> requestInjection(api));`
But, singletons are created after the `@configure` method is invoked. So, the singletons are always null when the control comes here.

Comment: You just need to bind the `@Path` annotated resource classes.  For example, if you to a basic `bind(Foo.class)` which is annotated with '@Path` then the `GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener` will inject them appropriately.  Hopefully you figured that out already (removing the duplication from the MyApplication class loading, everything should be managed through the GuiceResteasyBoostrapServletContextListener)